# Is this function globally Lipschitz?

Tags: real-analysis

I need help determining if the following function is globally Lipschitz (with respect to $y$):
$$ f(x,y) = \frac{xy}{x^2+y^2}$$
This is my attempt:
$$|f(x,y)-f(x,w)| = |x|\left| \frac{y}{x^2+y^2}-\frac{w}{x^2+w^2}\right|  = |x|\frac{|x^2-wy||y-w|}{(x^2+y^2)(x^2+w^2)}$$
but I got lost at this point. Thanks in advance. 

**Update**. Definition of Lipschitz with respect to $y$:
A function $f:D\subseteq\mathbb{R}^2\to \mathbb{R}$ is locally Lipschitz if there is a neighborhood around $(x,y_1),(x,y_2) \in D$ such that

$$|f(x,y_1)-f(x,y_2)| \le k|y_1-y_2|$$
for some constant $k >0$. It is globally Lipschitz with respect to $y$ if the condition holds for $D=\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: It is Lipschitz. Use the inequality $|wy| \leq \frac 1 2(w^{2}+y^{2})$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not clear to me as to what you mean by 'globally Lipschitz (w.r.t. $y$)' but we can show that $|f(x,y)-f(x,w)| \leq \frac 3 {|x|} |y-w|$ for all $y,z$ if $x \neq 0$. (Of course, $f(0,y)\equiv 0$). To see this continue from where you left off. Use the fact that $|x^{2}-wy| \leq x^{2}+\frac 1 2 w^{2}+\frac 1 2 y^{2}$. Considering these three terms separately and using the inequalites $x^{2}+w^{2} \geq x^{2},x^{2}+y^{2} \geq x^{2}$ you can show that $|f(x,y)-f(x,w)| \leq \frac 3 {|x|} |y-w|$ for all $y,z$ if $x \neq 0$.

Comment: If you want the Lipschitz constant to be independent of $x$ you are in bad luck. No such constant exists.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I updated the question with the definition I have, but I think I understand now. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Consider its behavior near $(0,0)$. It's defined in a neighborhood of the origin; if it were Lipschitz, we could extend it to be continuous (actually Lipschitz) there.

(That was for a Lipschitz condition as a function of two variables. For the unclear question actually asked, see below.)

As a family of functions $f_x(y) = \frac{xy}{x^2+y^2}$, each $f_x$ is Lipschitz, but the family is not equi-Lipschitz; the constant blows up as $x\to 0$.